# Get data from React props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

How to get data from `props` and be sure that data arrived properly. My issue is that in my class component I receive alarms from `props` and then I want to render table with the alarms, props sets asynchronously and I want to be sure that the data arrived and that I will be able to set a state. Below is my not nice try to solve it, but does not work (both `console.log` shows empty array):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      startDate: moment()
        .subtract(30, 'days')
        .startOf('day'),
      endDate: moment().endOf('day'),
      selectedSeverity: null,
      isChecked: true,
    });

    if(this.state.tableAlerts.length === 0){
      console.log('tableAlerts', this.state.tableAlerts)
      console.log('householdAlerts', this.props.householdAlerts)
      this.setState({ tableAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts })
    }
  }
```

The whole component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import T from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { moment } from 'react-moment';
import { t } from 'i18next';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { TimezoneLabel } from 'cloud-modules-user/build/TimezoneLabel';
import { Table, Radio } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { RangeDatePicker } from 'cloud-modules-user/build/RangeDatePicker';
import { SeverityFilter } from 'cloud-modules-user/build/Alerts';
import { fetchHouseholdAlerts } from '../Redux/Household.actions';

const alertSeverityText = ({ severity }) =>
  severity < 3 ? 'error' : 'warning';

const alertsBySeverity = alerts => {
  const groupedAndCounted = _.countBy(alerts, alertSeverityText);
  return severity => groupedAndCounted[severity] || 0;
};

const alertSeverityColor = {
  error: '#e05567',
  warning: '#f9b233',
};

export class HouseholdAlertsPure extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableAlerts: props.householdAlerts
    }
  }

  static propTypes = {
    householdAlerts: T.arrayOf(T.object).isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount(prevProps) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: moment()
        .subtract(30, 'days')
        .startOf('day'),
      endDate: moment().endOf('day'),
      selectedSeverity: null,
      isChecked: true,
    });

    console.log('prevprops', prevProps)

    // if(this.props.householdAlerts !== prevProps.householdAlerts){

    //   this.setState({ tableAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts })

    // }


    // if(this.state.tableAlerts.length === 0){
    //   console.log('tableAlerts', this.state.tableAlerts)
    //   console.log('householdAlerts', this.props.householdAlerts)
    //   this.setState({ tableAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts })
    // }
  }

  onChangeDate = e => {
    const startDate = moment(e.startDate).startOf('day');
    const endDate = moment(e.endDate).endOf('day');
    this.setState({ startDate, endDate });
    const {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
      fetchHouseholdAlerts,
      match: { params },
    } = this.props;
    fetchHouseholdAlerts(params.deviceGroupId, startDate, endDate);
  };

  selectOngoingAlerts = (e, data) => {
    const { isChecked } = this.state;
    this.setState( {isChecked : !isChecked} );

    const { householdAlerts } = this.props;
    // check whether alarm is ongoing
    if(isChecked){
      // filter ongoing alerts
      let filteredHouseholdAlerts = householdAlerts.filter((alert) => alert.setTimestamp < alert.clearTimestamp)
      this.setState( {tableAlerts: filteredHouseholdAlerts} )
    }else{
      // show all alerts, without any filter
      this.setState({tableAlerts: householdAlerts});
    }
  }

  handleOnChangeSeverity = (e, selectedOption ) => {

    console.log('e', e)
    this.setState( {selectedSeverity: e.option} )
    console.log('selectedSeverity', this.state.selectedSeverity)

  };

  setAlertForTable = () => {
    // if(this.state.alertsInitialised == true) return;
    console.log('setAlertForTable')
    // this.setState ( {alertsInitialised: true} )    
  }

  render() {

    console.log('test', this.props.householdAlerts)
    const { startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    const datesInitialized = startDate && endDate;
    // The dates are not set until the component is mounted.
    if (!datesInitialized) return null;

    const { householdAlerts } = this.props;
    const labels = {
      from: t('householdAlertsTimeRangeFrom'),
      to: t('householdAlertsTimeRangeTo'),
    };
    const numberOfAlert = alertsBySeverity(householdAlerts);



    return (
      <div className="alert-table">
        <section className="alerts-buttons">
          <div className="ongoing-box">
            <Radio toggle className="ongoing-checkbox"
              label="Ongoing alerts"
              value={ !this.state.isChecked }
              onChange={this.selectOngoingAlerts}
            ></Radio>
          </div>
          <SeverityFilter className="severity--button"
            onChange={this.handleOnChangeSeverity}
            value={this.state.selectedSeverity}
            option={this.state.selectedSeverity || 'all'}
          ></SeverityFilter>

          { this.setAlertForTable() }

          <div className="time-range">{t('householdAlertsTimeRange')}</div>
          <RangeDatePicker
            id="rangeDateSelector"
            labels={labels}
            onChange={e => this.onChangeDate(e)}
            selectedDateRange={[startDate, endDate]}
            filterDate={date => moment() > date}
          />
        </section>
          <div className="alert-table--statuses">
            <div aria-label="error">
              <div
                className="alert-table--statuses-item"
                style={{ backgroundColor: alertSeverityColor.error }}
              />
              <span className="alert-table--statuses-item-number">
                {numberOfAlert('error')}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div aria-label="warning">
              <div
                className="alert-table--statuses-item"
                style={{ backgroundColor: alertSeverityColor.warning }}
              />
              <span className="alert-table--statuses-item-number">
                {numberOfAlert('warning')}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

        <Table sortable>
          <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell style={{ width: '116px' }}>
                {t('householdAlertsSeverity')}
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell textAlign="left">
                {t('householdAlertsDevice')}
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell textAlign="left">
                {t('householdAlertsAlertName')}
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell textAlign="left">
                {t('householdAlertsAlertsMessage')}
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell textAlign="right">
                {t('householdAlertsTimestamp')}
              </Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>
          <Table.Body>
            {householdAlerts && householdAlerts.length !== 0 ? (
              _.map(
                householdAlerts,
                ({
                  id,
                  severity,
                  deviceName,
                  name,
                  setMessage,
                  setTimestamp,
                }) => (
                  <Table.Row key={id}>
                    <Table.Cell
                      className="alert-table--column-severity"
                      textAlign="right"
                    >
                      <div
                        className="alert-table--column-severity__status"
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor:
                            alertSeverityColor[alertSeverityText({ severity })],
                        }}
                      />
                    </Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell
                      className="alert-table--column-device"
                      textAlign="left"
                    >
                      {deviceName}
                    </Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell
                      className="alert-table--column-alert"
                      textAlign="left"
                    >
                      {name}
                    </Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell
                      className="alert-table--column-message"
                      textAlign="left"
                    >
                      {setMessage}
                    </Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell
                      className="alert-table--column-timestamp"
                      textAlign="right"
                    >
                      {moment(setTimestamp).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')}
                    </Table.Cell>
                  </Table.Row>
                ),
              )
            ) : (
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell colSpan={7}>
                  {t('householdAlertsMessageNoAlerts')}
                </Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            )}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
        <section className="timezone-wrapper">
          <TimezoneLabel />
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  householdAlerts: state.HouseholdReducer.householdAlerts,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchHouseholdAlerts };

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HouseholdAlertsPure),
);
```

Comment: Could you please show the componentn where you'r passing the prop householdAlerts?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(this.props.householdAlerts)` in render (before return) - just to be sure that `householdAlerts` are not always empty array?

Comment: Yes, I was trying and I got the data in render method before return.

Comment: That is good. Now, in your render you are using `this.props.householdAlerts` but also  `this.state.tableAlerts`. You have "two sources of throuth" for alerts which might cause bug.  Can you choose to use only data from props?

Comment: Not fun fact, when I changed in table to this.props.tableAlerts I do NOT see alerts ;/ #weirdo It is not my code, my job is to add filtering the alerts.

Comment: It works when I first make const { householdAlerts } = this.props; and then I use householdAlerts variable BUT I need to filter alerts and props are only-read ;/

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you could share code for entire component? Anyway, if I were you - will check `this.setAlertForTable()` and everything connected to it. Maybe this method uses initial state where alerts were empty array?

Comment: For rendering filtered alerts - use state, for initial alerts and for resting filtered alerts - use alerts from props

Comment: Is it expected behavior that data fetchig occure only when user is changing date?

Comment: It is expected that data are fetching on first load a page and then changing date. Yes.

Comment: Well, from the code we can see fetching doesn't happen when page loads (component get mounted)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210730/discussion-between-tomasz-waszczyk-and-danko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice to set initial values to state at the constructor, therefore use lifeCycles as componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate instead to manipulate the state.

---

```
 export class HouseholdAlertsPure extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // initial values for state
  this.state = {
  tableAlerts: [],
  startDate: null,
  endDate: null,
  selectedSeverity: null,
  isChecked: false      
 }
}

componentDidMount() {
 // values declared for state at component first load
 this.setState({
  startDate: moment()
    .subtract(30, 'days')
    .startOf('day'),
  endDate: moment().endOf('day'),
  selectedSeverity: null,
  isChecked: true,
  tableAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts
});

componentDidUpdate() {
// called whenever prop value changed
 if(this.props.householdAlerts !== this.state.tableAlerts) 
      this.setState({ tableAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts })
}

selectOngoingAlerts = (e, data) => {
 const { isChecked, tableAlerts } = this.state;
 this.setState( {isChecked : !isChecked} );
 // right now, { isChecked } still refer to construct abouve methond and prev value... 
// for more consist aproach, consider do the filtering logic direct at render without manipulate state
 if(!isChecked) { 
  this.setState( { tableAlerts: tableAlerts.filter((alert) => alert.setTimestamp < alert.clearTimestamp)} )
 } else { this.setState({tableAlerts}) }
}
 ...rest class...
}
```

---

Now at render, { this.state.tableAlerts } should contain the correct information

Comment: Why is it bad practice to set initial props in constructor? In React docs its suggested to do it there: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: If state dapends on props, state won't be updated automatically when props changes. That's why we listen for props changing in some component life cycle methods and updating state on prop change.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). It runs on each state and prop change.

This is an example of how it can be used:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { 
  if(this.props.householdAlerts !== prevProps.householdAlerts) { 
    this.setState({ tableAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts }) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: But how? I just included my componentDidUpdate and have empty array ;/

Comment: `componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { if(this.props.householdAlerts !== prevProps.householdAlerts) {  this.setState({ tableAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts })  }  }`