# Why I am getting the old state values after the props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I just want to understand why in the application I have following situation, below is my constructor of class component:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableAlerts: props.householdAlerts,
      initialAlerts: props.householdAlerts
    }

    console.log('householdAlerts', props.householdAlerts)
  }
```

in render function I have:

```
const { householdAlerts } = this.props;
```

My issue is that in constructor I got empty array, but in `render` funtion I have the data. Is it possible to get the data in constructor?

Comment: I think the problem is with *householdAlerts* prop itself. How do you set it in parent component?

Comment: may be your are looking for `getDerivedStateFromProps` rather changing the state each time ? or also, why using a state variable to store the prop variable ? the props will change because this is the natural flow of things, the state is like your internal system data base, meanwhile the props are the system arguments..

Comment: You get empty array in the constructor because it may be your initial value; the constructor is executed `once`. After the data arrives, your props change, and you have to manage the state variable; This is a very common bad pattern to copy props into state. It will add more complexity to your component. The better: use the prop directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very bad pattern when using the class component. You are ignoring any props updates when you copy the value into state. to manage it:

1. It requires you to manage two sources of data for the same variable: state and props. Thus, you need to add another render each time your prop change by setting it into state (don't forget to test on equality from prev and next values to avoid being in an infinite loop).
2. You can avoid setting the state each time your props change by using the [`getderivedstatefromprops`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) lifecycle method.

So the recommendation is: `just use the props; do not copy props into state`.

To learn more why you shouldn't, I highly recommend [this article](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to set your initial component state in the constructor like so because you gonna lose the ability to use { setState } method after to update this property/state.

The best practice is indeed to refer directly to the prop with { this.prop.householdAlerts }, and keep the state usage for local (or in child components} cases.

if anyhow you want to store props in component state for some reason, call it in lifeCycle -

---

```
  componentDidMount() { 
        const { tableAlerts, initialAlerts } = this.props;
        this.setState({ tableAlerts, initialAlerts });
     }
```

---

Comment: I see, but the issue is that I need to filter an array which I have in props, but props are read-only, so how I should them filter and then render?

Comment: There is no issue on filtering an array to get your data. `const myData = array.filter(filterFunc)`.

Comment: by calling array.filter() you create a new instance at memory with filtered values, so it is not supposed to be a problem to use directly this.props at render(). if you will add the rest of your code I will be able to modify my answer to be more relevant to your case...

Comment: The problem with you answer, is that, you only copy props into state ONE time; when the component mounts. but the component will be still alive receiving props many, many times while the app is up.

Comment: OK, filtering is not the issue, but then after filtering I need to render those filtered alerts, how to do it? Take a look at the whole my component: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60953545/get-data-from-react-props

Answer (score 0):

Hagai Harari is right. Nevertheless, your actual problem seems to be that during your initial rendering the array is empty. Can you ensure that the array has some items, when your component is rendered for the first time?

**First rendering** -> calls constructor

`<YourComponent householdAlerts={[]} />`

**Second rendering** -> updates component

`<YourComponent householdAlerts={[alert1, alert2, alert3]} />`

Comment: The reall issue is that he has to maintain that his state has always the same value as the props; which basically makes no sens, just use the props

Answer (score 0):

If you want initial state to have the prop value.Try something like this with 'this' keyword

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts,
      initialAlerts: this.props.householdAlerts
    }

    console.log('householdAlerts', props.householdAlerts)
  }
```

Comment: The constructor is executed just once, when the class is instantiated. It will not solve his issue.